# Legend graphing help in R

Tags: r, graph

So I am trying to add some graphs to my notes.  I have created a simple interest function that will plot several simple interest functions using different rates and I would like to add a legend that would simple say...
"i =: 0%, x%, y%, z%"  on one single line, where each 0,x,y,z is in the different color of the representative function using that interest rate.

I looked into the paste() function and attempted to make it one string but I am not sure exactly how to loop it into the int_seq and pull out each individual index and make it a different color then put it into a single string.

```
# indexs to be used
t = 0:50
int_seq = seq(0.025,0.10,by=0.025)  # intere rate sequence
colors = c("red","blue","green","orange")   #colors of interest rate seq
index = 1:length(int_seq)

# AV Simple Interest  (all good)
avSimple = function(i,t){
av = (1 + (i * t))
return(av)}

# Plot range for y-axis   (all good)
yrange = c(avSimple(min(int_seq),min(t)) * 0.95,
avSimple(max(int_seq),max(t)) * 1.05)

# Plots Simple Interest with different interest rates (all good)
plot(t,avSimple(0,t), type="l", main = "AV Simple Interest", xlab = "Time",
ylab = "AV", ylim = yrange)
# loops through the int_seq and plots line based on interest rate
# and specified color  (all good)
for (i in index) 
lines(t,avSimple(int_seq[i],t), col = colors[i])

# Adds legend to plot for different interest rates
# !!This is where I need the help, not sure best way to approach!!
legend(0,avSimple(0.075,50), c("i =: 0%", for (i in index) int_seq[i]), 
col = colors)
```

Comment: you can pass the full vector into `legend` (and also `lines`), so you won't need `for` loops such as: `legend(0, avSimple(0.075,50), sprintf('i =: %s%%', c(0, int_seq)), col = colors)` I'm not sure how you want the legend to look ?

Comment: `legend(0,avSimple(0.075,50), legend = paste0("i =: 0%, ", int_seq[index]), col = colors, lty = 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of legend you want. Since you say in one line, you might want to add `horiz = TRUE`, but here are some other options:

You can pass full vectors to `legend` so there is no need for a loop in this case. Just create a vector of labels but also use a vector of colors corresponding to each label (which you have already done).

```
# indexs to be used
t = 0:50
int_seq = seq(0.025,0.10,by=0.025)  # intere rate sequence
colors = c("red","blue","green","orange")   #colors of interest rate seq
index = 1:length(int_seq)

# AV Simple Interest  (all good)
avSimple = function(i,t){
  av = (1 + (i * t))
  return(av)}

# Plot range for y-axis   (all good)
yrange = c(avSimple(min(int_seq),min(t)) * 0.95,
           avSimple(max(int_seq),max(t)) * 1.05)


plot(t, type="n", main = "AV Simple Interest", xlab = "Time",
     ylab = "AV", ylim = yrange)
# for (i in index) 
#   lines(t,avSimple(int_seq[i],t), col = colors[i])

# Adds legend to plot for different interest rates
# !!This is where I need the help, not sure best way to approach!!

labs <- sprintf('i =: %s%%', c(0, int_seq))
labs2 <- paste0(c(0, int_seq), '%')


legend('topleft', legend = labs, col = colors, lty = 1, title = 'normal')

l <- legend('top', legend = rep('i =:', length(labs)), lty = 1,
            col = colors, text.width = max(strwidth(labs)) + 1, 
            title = 'right-justified')
text(l$rect$left + l$rect$w, l$text$y, labs2, pos = 2)

legend('topright', legend = labs, text.col = colors, title = 'colored')

legend('bottom', legend = labs, col = colors, lty = 1, horiz = TRUE,
       cex = .7, title = 'horizontal')
```

[image]

Comment: Is the best way to respond to an answer is "add comment"?  New to this site...   Thanks for the responses first off.  Not exactly what Im looking for though.  Maybe a legend isn't exaclt what I want because I do not need the corresponding line,  I simply want "i = : x%, y%, z%" but where x% is int_seq[1] with colors[1], y% is int_seq[2] with colors[2] and so on... No need for any colored sybols, just the colored interest rates.  The reason I wanted to loop is so that I can simply change the "int_seq" to any sequence and aslong as I have a color sequence of greater or equal length it will work

Comment: So maybe this is a better way to approach it... say I have a sequence of interest rates i=c(w,x,y,z) and a color sequence of color=c("red","green","blue","orange").  How could I create a string="w,x,y,z" where w,x,y,z are each different colors but are combined into a single lined horizontal string?

Comment: combine the colored and horizontal options?